# Regex matching using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm receiving a string as input, how can I get the values between the divs? For example:

```
var temp = "This is line one.<div>This is line two.</div><div><br></div><div>This is line three with a line break</div><div><br></div><div>&nbsp;</div><div><br></div><div>This is line four with a line break and space.</div>";
```

How can I get the text sentences out in an array? I have tried .filter and .each on the 'div' but they all miss the first one.

Answer (score 1):

To get the text between the divs:

```
var lines = $('div').map(function(el) {
    return $(el).text();
}).get();
```

NB: this won't extract `"this is line one"` because it's not between a `div`.

However, since you want to wrap each element with an `li` and insert them you can actually skip the array phase:

```
$('div').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    $('<li>', {'class': 'ui-state-default', text: text}').appendTo('#container');
});
```

Comment: Thanks Alnitak, but where do I put the $('div').each(function () {...?

Comment: Right now I am querying the html() of a div (and not the text(), because I want to capture line breaks as separate list items), but this does not feel right: $('#rawtext').html().$('div').each(function () {...